# In a Word Form how to detect the field the cursor is sitting on

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word Form with a few fields and a Command-Button. When the user clicks on that button I like the VBA code behind it to dump a certain text (e.g. "abc") in whatever field the cursor is on. All my searches show that I have to use the name of the field, but I don't know how to detect the Form Field that the cursor is sitting on.

Comment: could you upload your file somewhere in the Internet and provide a link here?

Comment: My code (except the line I don't know and are asking for) is very simple. Let's say there is a form with three Form-Fields (Text1, Text2, Text3), and a Command-Button. Following could be the code for CommandButton1:
`
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Looking for code that put "abc" in any of the three fields (Text1, Text2, Text3) in the form that the cursor is currently sitting on
ActiveDocument.FormFields..... = "abc"
End Sub
`

Comment: It won't work in the way you expect. By pressing button located in the document you changing selection from `FormField` to `button` therefore your selection is in the button now. I don't know which way you could check for `previous selection` which you should look for. Optionally change the logic of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was looking for a sort of property of FormFields. which I could not find any. However, the following single statement would place your desired text in any Form-Field that cursor is currently sitting on:

```
Selection.Range = "abc"
```